# Transformer removes heading labels

Tags: transformer, labels

**Question: Is there a way to retain/include headers once they go through a make_column_transformer?**

My dataframe has the usual columns and rows, but a header is included.

Example:

[image]

When I take the data through a transformer, the column labels are removed and the data is displayed in a scientific format.

Example of the first row:

[image]

This obviously makes it difficult to interpret the features. Is there a way to keep or add labels?

Comment: I voted not to close this question since I believe this can be answered meaningfully. However, you will need to be clearer about your motivation, and it may be helpful to include your function call to `make_column_transformer`. At a first glance I noticed that the transformation results in a different column width than before, so I'm not sure how the headers can be retained.

For reference, details about questions that are considered on-topic can be found [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).